Error making call: Too many objects of the specified type (PJ_ETOOMANY) [status=70010]
I am using PJSIP library in my C++ application to test calls. I am getting the Error making call: Too many objects of the specified type (PJ_ETOOMANY) [status=70010] when I tried to make more than 4 calls at a single execution.
I tried to make more than 4 calls in a single execution, and was expecting it to work successfully.

By following below steps, it resolved my problem.

Go to the PJSIP repository which you have cloned from GitHub.

Go to the file pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h and add the below lines to it.
#define PJSIP_MAX_TSX_COUNT               1000
#define PJSIP_MAX_DIALOG_COUNT            1000
#define PJSUA_MAX_CALLS                   1000

In the above code replace 1000 by your maximum number


